# Random Forest Crossvalidation in R

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

I am working on a random forest in R and I would like to add the 10- folds cross validation to my model. But I am quite stuck there.
This is sample of my code.

```
install.packages('randomForest')
library(randomForest)
set.seed(123)
fit <- randomForest(as.factor(sickrabbit) ~ Feature1,..., FeatureN ,data=training1, importance=TRUE,sampsize = c(200,300),ntree=500)
```

I found online the function `rfcv` in caret but I am not sure to understand how it works. Can anyone help with this function or propose an easier way to implement cross validation. Can you do it using random forest package instead of caret?

Comment: My understanding is that a properly built random forest model does not require cross validation, since each tree in the forest is built with an out of bag sample and checked against the unused remaining sample.  Why do you want to cross validate?

Comment: The size of my data set is a bit small about 50 features and 10000 samples. The data set is also very imbalanced only 200 of the total number of samples correspond to classes 1 and the rest to classs 2. All this without mentioning that I have to keep separate 30% of my data for testing the final model with unseen data. I would like to use k- fold cross validation to improve the model performace by better selecting the features.

Comment: I think you don't understand the basic premise of random forests.  Your data set isn't small; I spent years doing RF analyses of pharmaceutical data an order of magnitude _smaller_ than your data set and never had a problem.  You normally do _not_ cross validate an RF model; the algorithm used to build the forest implicitly does this for you.

Comment: For unbalanced data default RF OOB-CV could be unsatisfying as the model very easily will predict the most prevalent class only. I would recommend to either use strata or classweight options. Use cross-validated AUC to decide what settings are the promising for your objectives.

Comment: Hi Soren,As far as I know, I  am using strata. Strata and sampsize work in conjuction if strata is not specified, the class labels "as.factor(sickrabbit)" will be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to cross-validate a random forest model.  You are getting stuck with the `randomForest` package because it wasn't designed to do this.

Here is a snippet from [Breiman's official documentation](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#ooberr):

> In random forests, there is no need for cross-validation or a separate test set to get an unbiased estimate of the test set error. It is estimated internally, during the run, as follows:
>
> Each tree is constructed using a different bootstrap sample from the original data. About one-third of the cases are left out of the bootstrap sample and not used in the construction of the kth tree.
>
> Put each case left out in the construction of the kth tree down the kth tree to get a classification. In this way, a test set classification is obtained for each case in about one-third of the trees. At the end of the run, take j to be the class that got most of the votes every time case n was oob. The proportion of times that j is not equal to the true class of n averaged over all cases is the oob error estimate. This has proven to be unbiased in many tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post. It is a very clear explanation.